# What is the correct way to connect two tf trees?

Tags: ros-fuerte, robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a setup in which two separate tf trees are published, and I'd like to define one with regard to the other, but not from the base link/root node.

For instance two trees one with a tf_prefix, one without such that you might see:

```
/baseLink
  /link0
     /linkA0
     /linkB0
```

and

```
/ghost/baseLink
   /ghost/link0
      /ghost/linkA0
      /ghost/linkB0
```

And I want to define `/ghost/linkB0` as having an identity transformation from `/linkB0`.
However, since tf is set up with child and parent relationships as a tree and not as a free network, the correct way to do this is unclear.

The only way I can think to do it would be to rebuild the KDL::Tree that the sub-ordinate tree's RobotStatePublisher uses to originate at the desired link, but this would be non-trivial, and not offer a way to easily select a different link at will without doing the same thing for each desired combination.

Is there a better way to do this? Is it even possible given the current architecture?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58639/what-is-the-correct-way-to-connect-two-tf-trees?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your instincts are correct you can simply add a transform from "/baseLink" to "/ghost/baseLink".  The graph structure is independent of the names of the frames.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2013-03-19**:
Problem is that I want to go from `/linkA0` to `/ghost/linkA0` which cause `/ghost/linkA0` to have two parents and fail. I'm working on a work-around where I publish the transfrom from `/ghost/linkB0` to `/ghost/baseLink` as the transform from `/linkB0` to `/ghost/baseLink` to get the same effect.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-27**:
Just publish the link the other direction so it's a child, not a parent. You cannot bridge in the middle of a tree.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*If I got what you want correctly*: get the tf from the `/base_link` to `/linkB0` and the tf from `/ghost/base_link` to `/ghost/linkB0` and resolve to have the inbetween tf match an identity.

Either you make the nodes you want to manage the trees' roots or you resolve the inverse kinematics.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2013-03-20**:
This is pretty much the work-around I cam up with as well, but it's still a bit off as if certain transforms are updated more frequently than others, there will be more error than if the chain flowed from `/linkB0` to `/ghost/linkB0`

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-20**:
What time difference are you seeing?
At 50Hz on a wifi I sometimes see delays of half a second and tf view_frames requires multiple runs before drawing the correct trees. So it may well be normal that you have delays sometimes.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2013-03-20**:
It's not a measured one difference but inferred. If I publish the transform from `/linkB0` to `/ghost/baseLink` and the joint between  `/ghost/linkB0` and `/ghost/link0` changes before the next update to  from `/linkB0` to `/ghost/baseLink`, all transforms in the `/ghost/` tree will be incorrect.